# Unknown Water Source

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

I have water being diverted from underneath my foundation in one specific area from an unknown source. It's causing my foundation to settle and I have already had it leveled with piers.  I have confirmed that it is not a plumbing leak.  It only happens when it rains really hard.  I spoke to a plumber who told me he ran across this kind of issue before and after his customer investigated where their utility lines were, AT&T's lines were causing the problem and they ultimately were responsible for installing a sump pump to resolve the issue.  I know absolutely nothing about how utility lines run underground and how this could cause water to be diverted under a slab.  Does this make any sense to anyone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be on DIY.SE  (a homeowners'  help site)

Comment: Hope you can find someone to blame beside nature.

Comment: @SheilaPotts https://diy.stackexchange.com is that site. If the question is closed here as off-topic, you are allowed to cross-post it to another site.

Answer (score 2):

There are imaging companies that can read off X-rays or Radar and try to locate a broken utility housing or other underground trenches and natural or man made crevices.

It is possible that you have a soils engineering issue which will be uncovered by a soils investigation by an engineer.

Alternatively you can release the hydrostatic pressure by installing a drain and sump pump at a location upstream to this intermittent flow.